# Automatic deletion of a PostgreSQL table row when there are no more foreign keys pointing to it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need help figuring out the best practice to automatically delete a table row when there are no more foreign keys pointing to it.

I have 3 tables, Country, Region, and City. Cities belong to Regions, and Regions belong to Countries:

```
Country: id
Region: id, country_id (FK)
City: id, region_id (FK)
```

What I am trying to achieve is that whenever the user deletes all the Cities of a Region, such Region is automatically deleted as well. And similarly, if a Country has no Region left, deleting that Country automatically too.

Currently I am maintaining some inelegant application logic to do the cleanups, and I am trying to move that logic to the database level to be cleaner. I am not very experienced in PostgreSQL, but it seems like such logic could be implemented with triggers and functions. Would that be the right way to do it? Is there a simpler way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a trigger, but the trigger would be running stored code.

something like

`create trigger after delete on city for each row execute procedure city_deleted_check();`

where city deleted check is a trigger function that counts the number of cities in `old.region` and if zero deletes the region.

updates would need to be handled too,

Comment: Thank you Jasen :) So you confirm that there is not simpler built-in way to delete a row when there are no more foreign keys pointing to it from other tables?

Comment: if there was such a type of relational contsraint there would be no way to create a new region.

Comment: I use transactions to create them simultaneously.